# What is Magneto's helmet made of?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past, x-men-first-class

In the scene below from *X-Men: First Class*, Sebastian (Magneto's precessor) claims that his russian friends made the helmet for him (0:40)

In *Days of Future Past*, Magneto is able to use his power to get the helmet, so it must be a metal (I cannot find this scene on YouTube).

Therefore, what metal is this helmet made of?

Comment: there's a lengthy page about this helmet here https://xmenmovies.fandom.com/wiki/Magneto%27s_Helmet

Comment: Asked and answered here => https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/42873/magnetos-helmet-is-made-up-of-what-material